# Field extensions and irreducible polynomials

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field

Let $F=Z_p$ and $f = x^p - x -b$ be a irreducable polynomial under $F$. If E is the splinting field of $f$ and root $u \in E$ how can we show that $E = F(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the roots of $f$ are $u, u+1, u+2,....,u+p-1$ each of which $\in F(u)$. Hence the conclusion.

Observe that if $i\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ then $(u+i)^p-(u+i)-b=u^p+i^p-u-i-b=u^p+i-u-i-b=u^p-u-b=0$ since $u$ is a root.

Comment: Can you explain why those are the solutions or give me a reference or theorem to look at?

Comment: The field is characteristic $p$, so $(u+a)^p=u^p+a^p$.  Since raising to a $p$th power doesn't change elements of $F$, you know this is the same as $(u^p+a)-(u-a)-b=u^p-u-b$.